# Can I silence warnings when USING my method?

Tags: intellij-idea, java-8, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm writing a library method that emulates `?:` in Java.

> To be fair, I'm not sure how useful this is and I'm just testing it out personally for now.

```
/**
 * Shorthand for {@link #nullCoalescing(Object, Supplier, Object)}
 */
@NotNull
public static <RawType, BackupType> BackupType nc(
        @Nullable RawType possiblyNullValueContainer,
        @NotNull Supplier<BackupType> ifNotNull,
        @NotNull BackupType nonNullBackup) {
    return nullCoalescing(possiblyNullValueContainer, ifNotNull, nonNullBackup);
}

/**
 * Null Coalescing method: If {@code possiblyNullValueContainer} is {@code null}, {@code nonNullBackup} is returned;
 * else, {@code ifNotNull} is invoked and its result returned. The only caveat occurs when {@code
 * possiblyNullValueContainer} is a non-null {@link Optional}, wherein its {@link Optional#isPresent() isPresent()}
 * method is checked after discovering that it itself is not null.
 *
 * @param possiblyNullValueContainer The possibly-null value to check, or an {@link Optional} whose internal value
 *                                   is to be checked.
 * @param ifNotNull                  If {@code possiblyNullValueContainer} is not {@code null}, this is invoked and
 *                                   its result returned. The intended use is that this references a method that can
 *                                   be called on the aforementioned object, like {@code () ->
 *                                   possiblyNullValueContainer.toString()}. If this is {@code null}, you're just
 *                                   being silly and {@code null} will be returned.
 * @param nonNullBackup              If {@code possiblyNullValueContainer} is {@code null}, this is returned.
 * @param <RawType>                  The type of value to check for nullability
 * @param <BackupType>               The type of the backup values, which should not be null.
 *
 * @return Pretty much {@code possiblyNullValueContainer ? ifNotNull() : nonNullBackup}
 */
@NotNull
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // manually type-checked
public static <RawType, BackupType> BackupType nullCoalescing(
        @Nullable RawType possiblyNullValueContainer,
        @NotNull Supplier<BackupType> ifNotNull,
        @NotNull BackupType nonNullBackup) {
    if (null == possiblyNullValueContainer) {
        return nonNullBackup;
    } else if (possiblyNullValueContainer instanceof Optional) {
        // If they pass us an Optional, they must want us to check if it has a value inside rather than itself
        Optional nonNullOpt = (Optional) possiblyNullValueContainer;
        if (!nonNullOpt.isPresent()) {
            return nonNullBackup;
        }
    }

    if (null == ifNotNull) {
        Logger.getGlobal().severe("What are you doing?!");
        return null;
    } else {
        return ifNotNull.get();
    }
}
```

This is used like such:

```
// kinda like int i = value ?: 0
int i = nc(value, () -> value.intValue(), 0)

// less useful, I know, but still supported
String s = nc(optional , () -> optional.get(), "simple");
```

Which works fine. The problem comes when I use the full method name, like:

```
long l = nullCoalescing(value, () -> value.longValue(), 0L)
```

and I get this warning:

[image: Unboxing of 'nullCoalescing(value, () -> value.longValue(), 0L)' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException']

Which is clearly bubkus, because I manually checked each and every line in that method to ensure no NPE can be thrown while using it, and even sanity-checked by [running tests against it](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMS1Q3Qi12Nk9tQ0k). So, **how do I stop this warning from appearing whenever someone uses my `nullCoalescing` method?**

Note that this does *not* happen when using `nc` (presumably because it doesn't drill any deeper?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the fact that you are capturing the nullable `value` and unconditionally invoking a method on that reference within the lambda expression. The fact that the function will only be evaluated when `value` is not `null` is not visible to the audit tool, as you are checking the `possiblyNullValueContainer` parameter, not the captured value (they contain the same reference, but that seems to exceed the audit’s capabilities.

I recommend a different design anyway:

```
@NotNull
public static <RawType, BackupType> BackupType nullCoalescing(
        @Nullable RawType possiblyNullValueContainer,
        @NotNull Function<RawType,BackupType> ifNotNull,
        @NotNull BackupType nonNullBackup) {

    Objects.requireNonNull(ifNotNull);// don't provide fall-backs for illegal use
    Objects.requireNonNull(nonNullBackup); // be explicit

    if (null == possiblyNullValueContainer) {
        return nonNullBackup;
    }
    else if (possiblyNullValueContainer instanceof Optional) {
        // If they pass us an Optional,
        // they want us to check if it has a value inside rather than itself
        Optional<?> nonNullOpt = (Optional)possiblyNullValueContainer;
        if (!nonNullOpt.isPresent()) {
            return nonNullBackup;
        }
    }
    return ifNotNull.apply(possiblyNullValueContainer);
}
```

By using a `Function` which receives the reference which has been checked against `null`, every analyzing tool should recognize that the lambda expression is accessing a non-`null` value. Even tools not diving into the method won’t complain, as when using it like

```
long l = nullCoalescing(value, nonNull -> nonNull.longValue(), 0L);
```

the lambda expression doesn’t access a captured nullable value, but the lambda expression’s parameter only. As a bonus point, it’ll be potentially more efficient as a non-capturing lambda expression will be represented by a single instance rather than creating new instances on each capturing (as of the current implementation).

You may even use a simplified form, e.g.

```
long l = nullCoalescing(value, nonNull -> nonNull, 0L);
```

or

```
long l = nullCoalescing(value, Long::longValue, 0L);
```

By the way, the code above solves two other issues as well. By inserting a single `<?>`, you can get rid of the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and generally, it is not a good idea to handle an illegal state by logging and returning `null` in a method annotated with `@NotNull`, making the situation even worse than before…